# Should we explicitly cast cpp datatypes (int, float etc) to jni datatypes (jint, jfloat etc) when passing data from cpp to kotlin using jni

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

Let's say I have a Kotlin Static function that takes three parameters an Int, a Float, and a String.

```
object SampleObjectClass {

    fun SampleFunction (Int_data: Int, Float_data: Float, String_data: String) 
    {
        // TODO:
    }
}
```

Now, to call this function from cpp I can call it in two ways either by explicitly converting cpp int, float to jint, jfloat or letting jni do the conversion for me:

```
// variable declarations

int   int_data = 10;
float float_data = 10.10;
const char * string_data = "Hello From Cpp";
jstring java_string;

// converting char * to jstring

java_string = env->NewStringUTF (string_data);

// calling Kotlin function
// SampleClass is jclass of Kotlin's SampleObjectClass
// SampleMethodID is jmethodID of SampleFunction

// 1st way
env->CallStaticVoidMethod (SampleObjectClass, SampleFunctionMethodID, int_data, float_data, java_string)  

// 2nd way
env->CallStaticVoidMethod (SampleObjectClass, SampleFunctionMethodID, (jint) int_data, (jfloat) float_data, java_string)
```

both ways work, I'm aware that internally in 1st way also jni implicitly converts the cpp int and float to jint and jfloat before sending it to Kotlin.

So is there any advantage/disadvantage of converting data explicitly before sending it to Kotlin or both works exactly the same?

Also, just to make sure implicit conversation will work only for primitive types (int, float, long, double etc), it won't work for char * right?

Comment: As a general rule casting hides errors. So start by removing all casts, put your compiler on the highest warning level and compile. If there are no warnings then there is no need for casts. Deal with each warning as it arises. If you decide to suppress the warning by using a cast then use the lower powered C++ `static_cast` instead of bludgeon that is a C style cast. Again the aim is to reduce the chances of inadvertent conversions.

Comment: Whether implicit conversions work for `char*` or not depends on what you are implicitly converting to, which isn't clear to me from your question.

Comment: `it won't work for char * right?` -- Never cast string types unless you know *exactly* what you are doing.  Either you use the correct string type without casting, or you call the appropriate function(s) that accepts your string type without casting.  Casting string types is telling the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing", and most of the time, the programmer does not know what they're doing and just want to yell back at the compiler by applying ill-advised casts.

Comment: JNI doesn't do the conversion. The compiler does. No harm in letting it do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JNI interface is by design very coarse. As the comments above state, C-style casts will hide programming errors until runtime.

If you want a bare minimum of compile-time type checking, you can make the expected types explicit with a helper function like so:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <class... Args>
void CallStaticVoidMethod(JNIEnv *env, jclass receiver, jmethodID mid, std::tuple<Args...> arg_tup) {
    std::apply(&JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod,
      std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(env, receiver, mid), arg_tup));
}
```

The calling code can then be:

```
using sampleFunction_type = std::tuple<jint, jfloat, jstring>;

jstring x = env->NewStringUTF("hello there");
CallStaticVoidMethod(env, receiver, mid, sampleFunction_type{5, 9, x});
```

which will raise compile errors if you mis-match the argument count or -types.

Unfortunately, this is not clever enough to do Java subclass matches. For that you will need to write a lot more code that uses `IsAssignableFrom`, which is a runtime check, not compile-time.