# Constructing an object crashes jvm

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

Constructing an object crashes the jvm because the constructor is not found. The signature is correct and the constructor exists.
This is my new object code:

```cpp
JavaObject(jclass klass, const char *signature, ...) {
    std::cout << "constructing" << std::endl;
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, signature);
        
    jmethodID constructor = client->env->GetMethodID(klass, "<init>", signature);
    jobject newObject = client->env->NewObjectV(klass, constructor, arg);
    this->object = &newObject;
    va_end(arg);
}
```

And then:

```cpp
// javaClass->getClass() is java.lang.String
String(jcharArray v1) : JavaObject(javaClass->getClass(), "([C)V", v1) {}
```

edit: my class is `java.lang.String`. It has the constructor `String(char[])`. Running `javap -s` gives me the signature.

Comment: 1) *Constructing an object crashes the jvm because the constructor is not found* -- You should have error checking built into the function instead of just crashing.   Writing JNI code requires a *lot* of error checking and throwing exceptions back to Java if something goes wrong.  2) *The signature is correct and the constructor exists.* -- We have no idea if this is true or false since we do not have access to your environment.

Comment: unrelated: "this->object = &newObject" is _very_ fishy. That is taking the address of a local variable..

Comment: Are you sure `javaClass->getClass()` is the Class instance for String?

Comment: Voting to close as "needs debugging details". My money is on the comment above

Comment: @Botje `client->env` looks troublesome.  I'd bet the native code is caching the `JNIEnv` pointer value.  Doing that can cause the exact issues described here.  There's a good chance this is a dupe of [**What is the best way to save JNIEnv***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026030/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-jnienv).  And the TLDR answer to that is, "You **DON'T**"

Comment: @AndrewHenle Possible, but in my experience a shared JNIEnv tends to explode violently with an explicit error message instead of silently returning null. We'll never know unless OP responds.

Comment: @Botje  Well, OP's description doesn't rule that out.  ;-)  If the code isn't caching the `JNIEnv` value, the question definitely needs more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can never directly access the `va_list` value. You must call `va_arg` on it to get the arguments. `va_list` does *not* contain the first argument; it contains an unspecified type which can *access* the first argument by means of `va_arg`.

```
jobject newObject = client->env->NewObjectV(klass, constructor, va_arg(arg, ExpectedType));
```

But this is all academic, because we're in C++ in 2023, not C in 1991. There's no compelling reason to use `va_list` *at all* anymore; it's just a less type-safe version of [variadic parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). Your signature should look something like

```
template <typename... Ts>
JavaObject(jclass klass, const char *signature, const Ts&... args)
```

To use `args` (which is now type-safe), you can expand it in another argument list as

```
client->env->NewObjectV(klass, constructor, args...);
```

You can use it in a `std::tuple` or other type that expects parameter packs, to perform runtime operations on the pack as a single data structure.

```
auto my_args = std::make_tuple(args...);
```

You can't invoke undefined behavior by using parameter packs with the wrong types, as you'll just get a compiler error rather than the runtime just dying in exciting ways.

Comment: `env->NewObjectV` accepts `va_list` as an argument. Can we not pass arg into it?

Comment: Don't forget about `va_start` and `va_end`.

Comment: @DerekLi You should treat that function as legacy and prefer one of the other two variants instead. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#newobject-newobjecta-newobjectv `NewObject` can take a modern variadic parameter pack, and `NewObjectA` takes a traditional array.

Comment: This did not solve my problem. The jvm still crashes. Perhaps the method id is incorrect?

Comment: @DerekLi Not surprising this answer didn't help - it's just "Don't use that old C code, use the new C++" evangelism.  Even though the JNI interface is defined as a pure C interface, with "[C++] JNI functions are defined as inline member functions that expand to their C counterparts."  The C++ `env->NewObject()` **literally** just calls the C `NewObjectV` under the covers - just look in `jni.h` to see that.  This answer just directs you to write  extra C++ that does nothing functional.  I suspect you're caching the JNI `env` value - you can't do that.

Comment: Type safety is of no concern here. The expected arguments to the call are determined by the method being called, which is retrieved at runtime. I wrote a very crude compile-time type matching in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912238/1548468)

Comment: You can’t just ‘treat that function as legacy’. There are situations where it is the only choice.